# Short and fleet, what's the word?

Tags: riddle, word

```
Forward too fast
Accomplice of Bill
Arms of mass
Breaks the still
```

I'm going to start uploading daily riddles for fun during the weekdays. Some might be easier like this, others might be longer or more difficult, just something to work the mind a bit.

**Here's a hint for Bill**

> http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_ltx33awXZ81qfsmqno1.mp3
>  The song is an identifier for a movie, a famous duo of movies...

Comment: In general, but especially if you intend to make a running series of these, *please* use a descriptive title instead of "X Riddle #N".

Comment: Also note that unless they are very well-thought-out or innovative, daily riddles will get old fast, and will probably begin to garner downvotes, which is a message from the community that they've seen enough.

Comment: And okay, I'll make sure to plan them out. I want them to be a work for my brain and as well as for all of yours.

Comment: Is this likely to be easier for a specific national e.g. Americans?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'll add a hint to give more light on the Bill I'm referencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is

> a **gun** (or, possibly, its bullets)

Forward too fast

> A speeding bullet. Guns do their harm due to the tremendous speed with which the bullets travel, which carries a lot of kinetic energy in a small amount of mass.

Accomplice of Bill

> The hint is the "Twisted Nerve" theme song from Kill Bill, vols. 1 & 2.
>  The titular Bill uses a gun - a [Single Action Army .45 Long Colt with nickel finish, pearl "Bird's Head" grips, and custom muzzle brake.](http://www.imfdb.org/images/thumb/a/ab/Small_killbill-Bird%27shead.JPG/400px-Small_killbill-Bird%27shead.JPG)

Arms of mass

> Firearms, which shoot mass (bullets) at their target
>  Also, and as intended by OP, people who have massive (muscular) arms are colloquially said to have "big guns".

Breaks the still

> They're loud, breaking the stillness.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke Thanks for the hint. (Removing your comment to preserve the mystery for other would-be solvers.)

Answer (score 5):

> Teddy Roosevelt

Forward too fast

> Famous for the Rough Riders' charge up San Juan Hill in the Spanish-American War

Accomplice of Bill

> Famous for being William McKinley's Vice President

Arms of mass

> Famous for amateur boxing

Breaks the still

> Famous for being commissioner of New York City police during a pre-Prohibition crackdown on public drunkenness and Sunday saloon operations ("blue laws")

Comment: Not a person, but I love the interpretation. Not that kind of still.

Answer (score 0):

is it

> snake (or black mamba)

Forward too fast

> snakes move faster in forward direction

Accomplice of Bill

> bill had a nick name snake-charmer, also Beatrix's nickname is black mamba

Arms of mass

> snakes can take shapes as if they have no bones

Breaks the still

> no idea yet

Comment: Nope, nice idea though. The first three lines can be taken as different interpretations of the word.